# doesFileExist not finding files that exist

Tags: haskell

So I have a directory, /test, and in it are the following files:

```
test.txt  
BasicLoop.vm  
FibonacciSeries.vm  
StackTest.vm  
test.vm
```

I'm trying to read all the .vm files into one massive string, and in order to do so I thought to use `filterM doesFileExist dir` where `dir` is the result of `getDirectoryContents`, to remove directories and symlinks and whatever, but when I test it, the result of that filter is just BasicLoop.vm and test.vm. None of them are empty, and they show up when I peek at the contents of `dir`, so they clearly do exist. Why does the function say they don't?

Comment: Which result do you get with `getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents >>= filterM doesFileExist`?

Comment: What's your code exactly? I'm finding your question a little hard to follow.

Comment: directory x = do ---
    dir <- getDirectoryContents x ---  
    xs <- filterM doesFileExist dir ---
    out <- stream xs ---
    return out  ---
  
(Sorry, I don't know how to linebreak comments and have a remarkably poor grasp of pointfree style)

Comment: @Arii it would be better just to edit your post, but here it's OK.

Comment: @Arii The pointful do-block equivalent of the code in my comment would be `do { dir <- getCurrentDirectory; entries <- getDirectoryContents; filterM doesFileExist entries }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the function say they don't?

Because `getDirectoryContents` returns the file and directory names, not the full filepath. To see that, try something like:

```
λ:> getDirectoryContents "test"
["data","..","test.dats","."]
```

Comment: ... What? `getDirectoryContents` returns `[FilePath]` and both `readFile` and `doesFileExist` takes a `FilePath`... I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Arii `getDirectoryContents foo` returns `FilePath`s that are relative to `foo`, but `doesFileExist` treats relative filepaths as being relative to the current directory (which may be different from `foo`).

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes much more sense. I suppose the follow up would be, how do I go about solving that?

Comment: @Arii If `bar` is a list element returned from `getDirectoryContents foo`, then `foo </> bar` will be an absolute path to `bar`.

Comment: Got it, `withCurrentDirectory`. Everything's good. Now, I'm a bit of a noob here, should I mark this as the answer if the answer was in the comments? EDIT: Oh, yeah, that works too.